# Pass parameters from webflow to redirected page

Tags: spring, attributes, redirect, spring-webflow

I have this issue.
I redirect the user to /login page after registration, but I want to pass attribute from end-state of webflow to login.html that says something like "you have registered successfully". How can I accomplish that?

Edit: By the way I use thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

when User clicks on Signup button the method which handles the registration there you need to add Model and insert the message as the attribute and pass to the login page.

example:

```
    //Suppose these is the method which handles the registeration
   void register(Model model)
   {
     model.addAttribute("Message","You are successFully Login");
    return "loginPage";
   }
```

And in login.jsp you can get the Message object as:

```
${Message}
```

Comment: One remark: This doesn't work with Spring Webflux (Spring 5), I had to solve it with URL params there, which is a bit ugly though. There is an open issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16026